# Increasing default string value length when creating Test Table Storage in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Is it possible to increase the default value length of string values from nvarchar(1000) to something higher?

So that I don't need to edit the tables in SQLEXPRESS each time I recreate the tables.

Comment: You have this question tagged windows-azure-storage, but are you actually using SQL Azure? Azure Table Storage shouldn't have any limit on string length.

Comment: This was an issue in the pre-Nov CTP, when you're testing your Table Storage locally where an SQL Express database is used by Azure to simulate Table storage. I'm not sure if it is still an issue now. This question may no longer be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The simulated azure storage doe suse a SQL server and does not suppert everything the same way it works in Azure. Azure is also continously updated while your simulated storage is not. I suggest you do the same thing I did when I had a problem with different implementations; run your tests against a special storage account (in azure) for development. That way you know it will work.